# Regular Expression word boundary breaks on '-'

Tags: javascript, regex, string, node.js

I have a string in the following format.

> "ad60 ad60-12 ad60 12-ad60"

now I want to find the matches only where "ad60" is written.

I started off with

> /\bad60\b/i

but regex finds that '-' is not part of the character string. which returns 4 matches.
I tried many things but they all either return 4 matches or return nothing.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Just where 'ad60' is written, surrounded by space start of line end of line, but if its somewhere within a string it should not match.
as in "12-ad60" and ("ad60-12") should not match.

Comment: @anubhava the "ad60" can chnage, it's just a token I enter.

PS: I am a noob at Regex

Comment: List possible rules what you have and what you want to get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
var s = "ad60 ad60-12 ad60 12-ad60";
var r = s.replace(/(^|\s)ad60(?=\s|$)/g, "$1@@");
//=> @@ ad60-12 @@ 12-ad60
```

Comment: That is just amazing, s.match(/(^|\s)ad60(?=\s|$)/ig) did the trick

Comment: Please explain the answer a bit. will appreciate it

Comment: Sure let me explain. `(^|\s)` matches line start OR space. `(?=\s|$)` is a positive lookahead that looks ahead a space or line end.

Answer (score 0):

this should find any word starting from letter

```
/[a-z][a-z\d]+/i
```

**ADDED**

if you wish to find any words which are included ad60 string try this

```
/[a-z\d\-\_]*ad60[a-z\d\-\_]*/i
```

but words separated by space will not get in result

Comment: It is no good, I think I was not clear enough in my question. I want to find what ever is inside "\b" tags, "\b" means string boundary, but a word written as 'ad60-something' matches ad60 from it, which is something I don't want, thanks though

Answer (score 0):

```
"ad60 ad60-12 ad60 12-ad60".match(/(^ad60\s+)|(\s+ad60$)|(\s+ad60\s+)|(^ad60$)/ig);
```

will result in ["ad60 ", " ad60 "] 
then you can trim the white spaces in matched elements.